# How to solve $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-n$?

Tags: limits

I would like to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-n = 2,$$
but have no ideas on how to proceed with this limit. Any hint? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a hint.
$$a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$$

Comment: @mathlove: I fixed that! :)

Comment: grrr, silly errors,...

Answer (score 1):

Hint : factorize by $n$ and use a Taylor expansion of $f(t)=(1+t)^\frac{1}{3}$ when $t$ is near zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-n$$

Using $\bf{A.M\geq G.M}\;,$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+1)+(n+2)+(n+3)}{3}\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$

So we get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n+2\geq\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$

and equality will hold when, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n+1)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n+2) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n+3)$$

So we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-n = 2$$

Comment: This is very sloppy. You are treating infinite quantities as numbers.

Comment: indeed, I must second @GrumpyParsnip 's opinion, it is not quite clear to me why this is should be a valid way to solve this problem, actually $\lim_{n\to\infty} n+2$ is not even defined in $\mathbb R$. Could you elaborate a bit?